# pass member object of ArrayList to function by value.how does the native object took the value?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am using ready code from [this](https://github.com/VKEDCO/DrawTouchDrive_00001/blob/master/TicTacToeView.java).

in the code we have circles shapes`ArrayList<Circle> mCircles;`
the shapes are created in a custom view class. and drawn in the view see like the following

```
private void createCircles() {
    mCircles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    mCircles.add(new Circle(30, 30, 20));
    mCircles.add(new Circle(120, 30, 20));
}
private void drawCirclesOnCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
    for (Circle c : mCircles) {
        canvas.drawCircle(c.getCurrentX(), c.getCurrentY(), c.getRadius(),
                mForeCirclePaint);
    }
}
```

in summary the handle touch function for the circle shape is

```
private void handleTouchedCircle(MotionEvent me, Circle c) {
    final float me_x = me.getX();
    final float me_y = me.getY();
    final int action = me.getAction();
    switch (action) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        c.setActionDownX(c.getCurrentX());
        c.setActionDownY(c.getCurrentY());
        c.setActionMoveOffsetX(me_x);
        c.setActionMoveOffsetY(me_y);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        c.setCurrentX(c.getActionDownX() + me_x - c.getActionMoveOffsetX());
        c.setCurrentY(c.getActionDownY() + me_y - c.getActionMoveOffsetY());
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        c.restoreStartPosition();
        break;
    }
}
```

this make the circle move. my question how does the original circle object in ArrayList take values from the above function? 
this is how we called it

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // 1. get the x and y of MotionEvent
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    // 2. find circle closest to x and y
    Circle cr = findCircleClosestToTouchEvent(x, y);
    // 3. find cross closest to x and y
    Cross cx = findCrossClosestToTouchEvent(x, y);
    // 4. compute euclid distances to find which is
    // closer - circle or cross
    float dtcr = euclidDist(cr.getCurrentX(), cr.getCurrentY(), x, y);
    float dtcx = euclidDist(cx.getMidX(), cx.getMidY(), x, y);
    // 5. if distance to closest circle is smaller
    // handle the circle; otherwise, handle the cross
    if (dtcr < dtcx) {
        handleTouchedCircle(event, cr);
    } else {
        handleTouchedCross(event, cx);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I searched a little people say there is no pass by reference in Java (it has different meaning from c++), so what is the criteria
thank you

Comment: Pass by reference is also a Java term. What does `findCircleClosestToTouchEvent` do? Does it return from that Arraylist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. here is the code that calls                                                    private Cross findCrossClosestToTouchEvent(float x, float y) {
        Cross c = mCrosses.get(0);
        float dist = euclidDist(c.getMidX(), c.getMidY(), x, y);
        float tempdist = 0;
        for (Cross cx : mCrosses) {
            tempdist = euclidDist(cx.getMidX(), cx.getMidY(), x, y);
            if (tempdist < dist) {
                c = cx;
                dist = tempdist;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
it finds the nearest circle.